# Using $\ln (\cos x)=\frac{-x^2}{2}-\frac{x^4}{12}+...$, approximate $\ln 2$ in terms of $\pi$

Tags: calculus, taylor-expansion, approximation

> Using $f(x)=\ln (\cos x)=\dfrac{-x^2}{2}-\dfrac{x^4}{12}+\dots $, approximate $\ln 2$ in terms of $\pi$.

I know $\cos(x)$ will never be two - so what can I actually substitute in to get something in terms of pi?

Comment: Approximate what?

Comment: How about $\ln(1/2)$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Notice that the natural logarithm has a useful property
$$\ln\left(a^b\right)=b\ln(a)$$
So in fact, we only have to get a value of cosine that is an exponent of $2$ to approximate $\ln(2)$.

Further notice that $$\cos\left(\frac \pi 4\right)=\frac {1}{\sqrt{2}}$$

Comment: Also $\cos(\pi/3)=1/2$

Comment: That works too!